# Torque and lever in a circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics, torque

> Calculate the force (F) required for a person in a wheelchair to get onto the pavement with height h = $10$ cm. The total weight of the person and the wheelchair is m = $70$ kg and the radius of the wheelchair is r = $30$ cm. See figure
> [image]

I am having trouble understanding how to solve this problem. I have the answer key but I don't understand how things are derived. The answer key states:

> At the moment when the wheel is lifted from the ground the normal force = 0, and only three forces act on the wheel: F, mg and the force from the pavement at point A. We choose A as our rotation axis to avoid this force:
>
> d = √ (r$^2$ - (r-h)$^2$) = √ ($2$hr - h$^2$) (lever for mg)
>
> lever for F: r-h
>
> т$_A$ = mgd - F($2$r-h) = mg(√ ($2$hr - h$^2$)) - F($2$r-h) = 0
>
> Then you solve for F: F = $\frac{mg(√ (2hr - h^2))}{(2r-h)}$ = $300$ N
>
> [image]

I know that $т = F * l$ but how do I know that the lever is supposed to be that for mg? And if the force F is not given, do you always take the lever of the force as well?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I know that the lever is supposed to be that for mg?

In my opinion, to compute torque, it is more straightforward to consider the **lever as the segment joining the rotation axis and the point where the force is applied**, and then to take into account only the component of the force **orthogonal** to the lever. The radial component of a force does not contribute to torque.

Therefore, $r$ is the lever (distance between the point $A$ and the center of the circle, that I will call $O$) and $m\vec{g}$ has to be *projected* along the distance orthogonal to $AO$.

Consequently, when calculating the torque due to gravity, the lever is $r$ itself, but the force is not $mg$ but rather $mg\sin\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the angle between the segment $AO$ and the vector $m\vec{g}$, highlighted in red in the following figure. The components of $m\vec{g}$ are drawn in orange.

[image]

What we know about $\alpha$ is that $ r \cos\alpha = r-h$, which means that
$$\sin\alpha = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2\alpha} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{(r-h)^2}{r^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{2hr-h^2}}{r}.$$
The torque is finally
$$\tau_g = mgr\frac{\sqrt{2hr-h^2}}{r} = mg \sqrt{2hr-h^2},$$
which is the same as in the solution you posted.

Indeed, this is equivalent to the solution's way to compute the torque, which consists in taking the whole force *as it is* and considering as lever the **distance between the rotation axis and the line on which the force lies**. I tried to sketch this in the next figure: the lever is the distance between $A$ and the red line, i.e. the red, dashed segment. In this case, the lever would then be the "horizontal" side of the triangle in orange below; you can compute its length via Pythagoras' theorem.

[image]

> And if the force F is not given, do you always take the lever of the
> force as well?

I am not really sure to understand what you mean. When $\vec{F}$ is absent, $m\vec{g}$ will be compensated by the forces $n$ and $R$, both in terms of *force* balance, as well as in terms of *torque* balance. These *two* requirements allow you to determine the *two* unknown forces, $n$ and $R$, in the static condition.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain! Truly appreciate it!